# How do you get an XmlWriter to write an HTML tag with xmlns and xml:lang?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xmlwriter

I am using an XmlWriter to render HTML. How can I get an XmlWriter to emit a proper  tag that looks like this?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

here is what I have so far

```
    var xml = XmlWriter.Create(HtmlFileName, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true});
    xml.WriteDocType("html", "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd", null);
    xml.WriteStartElement("html");            
    xml.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
    ...
```

The last line crashes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var xml = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
        {
            xml.WriteDocType("html", "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd", null);
            xml.WriteStartElement("html", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
            xml.WriteAttributeString("xml", "lang", "", "en");
            xml.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```